# Generating form rows with variable names in symfony 3.4 with twig and form builder

Tags: php, twig, formbuilder, symfony-3.4

Using symfony 3.4 (php)

I have a form to edit the user profile of the current user with client-dependent attributes. So I generate the form with a UserType inheriting from `Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType`, adding the attributes with an EventListener depending on the client:

```
$form->add('ca-' . $attribute->getId(), TextType::class, array('label' => $attribute->getAttributeName() . ':'));
```

Now how can I generate the rows for this in my twig template? It should be something like

```
{{ form_row(form['ca-' . attribute.id]) }}
```

but it seems that I can't bind the integer `attribute.id` with a period. Is there a way to access this variable here? Accessing attribute `address` works fine with the following code:

```
{{ form_row(form.address) }}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
{{ form_row(form['ca-' ~ attribute.id]) }}
```

To concat string and variable in twig, just use `~`

Comment: That actually works an is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!!